# How to list data in a vertical format in Infragistics wingrid

Tags: infragistics, wingrid

Normally (and naturally), each entry in a list is presented in a row in the grid control, but there're cases when I need to show each entry in a vertical format, i.e. in a column.

For example, for a simple grid like:

- Name Email Age Address
- John j@a.com 30 John's address
- Joe j@b.com 30 Joe's address
- Tom t@c.com 30 Tom's address

Is it possible to show it in Infragistics wingrid as:

- Name John Joe Tom
- Email J@a.com j@b.com t@c.com
- Age 30 30 30
- Address John's adddress Joe's address Tom's address

One reason of doing this is because there're too many fields for each entry and the user thinks it would be easier to navigate if they're all in the same column instead of the same row.

I know I can manually transform the original data source and build another business object in the vertical format, but it feels awkward because the new BO doesn't really present the nature of what it really means.

Any help is very much appreciated..Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nico is right. `CardView` should do what you are looking for here.

Please let me provide you more details about this property:

1. This property determines whether the Band is in CardView mode.
2. Once set on any Band, all of the descendants of this Band will become hidden.
3. In most cases the best place to be set would be in the `InitializeLayout` event of your `UltraGrid`.

In order to achieve the desired look you would probably use the following code:

```
private void ultraGrid1_InitializeLayout(object sender, InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
{
      //Setting the desired Band to be in a CardView mode
      e.Layout.Bands[0].CardView = true;

      //Restrict the maximum card area rows
      e.Layout.Bands[0].CardSettings.MaxCardAreaRows = 1;

      //Decide if  the caption should be shown
      e.Layout.Bands[0].CardSettings.ShowCaption = false;

      //Remove the CardSpacing so it would like closer to what you are expecting            
      e.Layout.Bands[0].Override.CardSpacing = 0;
}
```

For more general information about the CardView style please take a look [here](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2011.1/CLR2.0/?page=Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v11.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridBand~CardView.html).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the `CardView` property as active?

This should solve your problem.